# What is the purpose of 'arguments' in square brackets? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, brackets, square

I ran into this while watching a tutorial.  Haven't seen it before, and I'd like to know what's going on here.

```
    Application["ApplicationStartDateTime"] = DateTime.Now;
```

Here it is in context:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        Application["ApplicationStartDateTime"] = DateTime.Now;
    }
    protected void Application_End()
    {
        Application.Clear();
    }
}
```

The application_Start method is boiler plate except for the StartDateTime line that was added with little explanation as to why.
Specifically, I want to know about the square brackets.  I'm aware of arrays, and I'm aware of annotations, but this looks different.

Comment: its called indexer (similar to dictionary)

Comment: **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/index-operator**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an [*indexer*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/indexers). Basically it's meant to look like the use of an array, but it can have multiple parameters, and they don't have to be integers. Just like a property, an indexer can have a get accessor and/or a set accessor.

They're declared like this:

```
public class Container
{
    public string this[int x, int y]
    {
        get { /* code here */ }
        set { /* code here using value */ }
    }
}
```

That's an indexer of type `string` that has two `int` parameters. So we could then write:

```
Container container = new Container();
string fetched = container[10, 20];
container[1, 2] = "set this value";
```

Indexers are most commonly used for collections:

- `IList<T>` declares a read/write indexer of type `T` with a single `int` parameter
- `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` declares a reader/write indexer of type `TValue` with a single `TKey` parameter